# Jquery onclick change dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

following is my JQuery  onclick function. An event applied on image.

this code is changing onclick event depending on data values received.
I added a break point in code as shown below in code.
A strange thing that is happening is that on my first click interpreter pass through my code one time only which is normal.

but when i click 2nd time it pass 2 times

on third click it pass 4 times

5th click 8 and so on

i.e number of call backs invoke per click are increasing exponentially. Now my question is why this is happening.

NOTE: all variables are defined properly but for simplification i striped down rest of code.

```
updateUser = function (user, block) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?option=com_contentbuilder&controller=myActicateUser",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                var pinID = "#pin" + user;
                user = data[0]; 
>>breakpoint        if (data[1] === "0") {

                    jQuery(pinID).click(function () {
                        updateUser(user, "1")
                    });
                    jQuery(pinID).attr("src", tack);


                } else if (data[1] === "1") {

                    jQuery(pinID).click(function () {
                        updateUser(user, "0")
                    });
                    jQuery(pinID).attr("src", tick);

                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

what i have already tried is

```
 if(data[1]==="1"){
                             jQuery(pinID).unbind();
                             jQuery(pinID).removeAttr("onclick");
                             jQuery(pinID).click(function(){updateUser(user,"0")});
}
```

Comment: Mary anyone as answer

Comment: Mary anyone as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Click,based on jquery plugin, You could use

```
jQuery(pinID).live("click",function(){updateUser(user, "1")})

or

jQuery(pinID).on("click",function(){updateUser(user, "1")})
```

May be This would help you out . Because these will dynamically bind and handle click event to your elements.

Answer (score 4):

That is because each time you call `updateUser` it binds additional `click` handlers on the same elements.

Either `unbind` first (*`jQuery(pinID).unbind('click').click(...)`*) or add the binding outside the `updateUser` only once

Comment: i editted my question. how i tried alreadly is in eddited portion

Comment: @arslan, you would need to do the same for the `(data[1] === "0")` scenario.. (*also no need to remove the `onclick` attribute*)

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for both of you Gaby and Anand, 
the reason i am writing my own answer is that i solved problem using both replies so thats 
why i prefered to write my own answer.

what i found is that is as follow

following is my event registring  tag

```
<img src="hello.png" onlick="updateUser()"/>
```

now what i observed wass that following line

```
jQuery(pinID).unbind();
```

was unable to unbind the above onclick event unless onclick attribute from img tag is not removed. So before unbind i added following statement

```
jQuery(pinID).attr("onclick", "");
```

it started working. but one other problem was that unbind also does not work for events registered with

```
jQuery(pinID).click(function () {
                    updateUser(user, "0")
                });
```

So i replaced the above line as proposed by Anand

```
jQuery(pinID).on("click",function(){updateUser(user, "1")})
```

And final working code was as follow

```
success: function(data) {

                            if (data){
                                var pinID="#pin"+user;
                                user=data[0];
                                if(data[1]==="0"){
                                    jQuery(pinID).attr("onclick","");
                                    jQuery(pinID).unbind();
                                    jQuery(pinID).on("click",function(){updateUser(user,"1")});
                                    jQuery(pinID).attr("src",tack);


                                }
                                else if(data[1]==="1"){
                                    jQuery(pinID).attr("onclick","");
                                    jQuery(pinID).unbind();                                        
                                    jQuery(pinID).on("click",function(){updateUser(user,"0")});
                                    jQuery(pinID).attr("src",tick);
                                }


                            }

            }
```

And thanks for both of you once again **Anand** and **Gaby**

Comment: no it didnt work with  unbind only. you have to use this too jQuery(pinID).attr("onclick","");

Comment: i wasted full day to debug this situation. above answer include the working code.

Comment: Sorry mistakenly mentioned. Try without UnBind(). It'll work.